# Any alternative web servers besides IIS for running ASP.Net 4?

Tags: asp.net

Just wondering.  I know Abyss will run ASP.Net 3.5 OK.

Comment: I honestly can't imagine why you'd want to not use IIS 7.

Comment: @Chris - for testing purposes, especially in a continuous integration environment.

Comment: I guess this point is now moot now that IIS Express is in the wild.  I feel bad for the makers of Abyss, I was hoping they would come out with a new version that supported .Net 4 fully. I bet it never comes about now, or even if it does it is a moot point.  Other than Casini I didn't find much out there.  IIS Express will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No clue what Abyss is, but you can host ASP.NET application in just about anything you want to with a bit of coding.  There is an entire chapter devoted to this topic in Esposito's "Programming ASP.NET" book.

Comment: Abyss is a small lightweight web server that I've used in the past, you can Google it.  Worked pretty well with ASP.Net 3.5 for some testing I did, was hoping to use it on a beater box that can't support Windows Server 2008 very well. Allegedly new version of Abyss is coming out in June, got a beta link, but haven't played with it yet.  I'm not sure how it will the IIS integration features in .Net 4.0 would be equivalent-ed (if that is a word).  I guess I'll wait and see.

Answer (score 4):

Keep an eye on [Cassini Developers Edition](http://cassinidev.codeplex.com/).

It hasn't been updated yet but I'm sure it will support 4.0 after Microsoft releases the updated Cassini code after the official 4.0 launch.

Comment: Yes, I am in the middle of a significant refactor of CassiniDev and will release 4.0 soon. But in the meantime, if you do not require to use an IP other than loopback, I have illustrated a means of reliably controlling WebDevHost (the core of VS Dev Server) here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/test-with-vs-devserver-2.aspx (see the second example) p.s. Hey kervin! ;-)

Comment: lol, hey Sky.  Great job with CassiniDev, it's a very useful project.  I always recommend it.

Comment: I just released the CassiniDev 3.5.1/4.0.1 beta with a simple test fixture example if you are interested.

Comment: me again - just released a VS 2008 dev server replacement with integrated logging. VS10 coming soon. http://skysanders.net/subtext/archive/2010/05/22/release-cassinidev-for-visual-studio-2008-a-drop-in.aspx